# one search button and two text boxes if statement logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a search criteria to find information about a vehicle based onto two kind of information. The first is container name and custom declaration

I have one button with text search and two text boxes, the first text for container name and the second for custom declaration.

I'm using EF to Join three tables with contains like this:

```
var query = (from con in db.Containers
             join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
             join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
             where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
             v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId && con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text)
             select new
             {
                 cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                 vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                 VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
                 vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                 vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                 vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                 cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
             }).ToList();



var query2 = (from con in db.Containers
              join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
              join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
              where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
              v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId && con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text)
              select new
              {
                  cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                  vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                  VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
                  vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                  vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                  vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                  cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
              }).ToList();
```

the first query with contains condition for container name `(txtContNo.Text)`

the second query2 with contains condition form container name `(txtCust.Text)`

and this is the if statement I used to handle which query to execute :

```
if (txtContNo.Text != null)
{
    rptVehl.DataSource = query;
    rptVehl.DataBind();
}
if (txtCust.Text != null)
{ 
    rptVehl.DataSource = query2;
    rptVehl.DataBind();
}
```

> rptVehl is repeater tool

Every time I compile the code no errors but when I enter container name in (txtContNo.Text) no data appear, also when I use the tracePoint the code in the first if statement which belong to (txtContNo.Text) doesn't hit.

When I enter the custom declaration it worked and gives me data about what I search?

> Note that : if I omit the first if statement, the second works fine
>   and gives me the desired output.

I think there's something wrong with the if logic. Can someone figure out?

Comment: You can make general query for both the conditions. if user enters value in both the textboxes then your if logic will not work.

Comment: @SanthoshNayak  How could i do that please explain?

Comment: Put break point and check whether any values are there in txtContNo.Text when you search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried, you can try something like this:

```
var query = (from con in db.Containers
             join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
             join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
             where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
             v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId &&( con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text==null?con.cont_Name:txtContNo.Text)||con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text==null?con.cont_customdec:txtCust.Text))
             select new
             {
                 cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                 vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                 VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
                 vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                 vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                 vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                 cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
             }).ToList();



    rptVehl.DataSource = query;
    rptVehl.DataBind();
```

Comment: thank you very much, ithworks fine with txtContNo.Text
but when i search for txtCust.Text it gives me two records with the same info in the repeater?

Comment: modified condition

Comment: tested but the same problem appeared

Answer (score 1):

I would make a slight change in the Linq and make it one:

```
var query = (from con in db.Containers
             join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
             join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
             where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
             v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId

             select new
             {
               cont_name = con.cont_Name,
               vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
               VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
               vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
               vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
               vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
               cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
             }).ToList();

if(txtConNo.Text != "")
{
  query = query.Where(con => con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text))
}

if(txtCust.Text != "")
{
  query = query.Where(con => con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text))
}
```

Finally, bind to the `GridView`:

```
rptVehl.DataSource = query;
rptVehl.DataBind();
```

Comment: can you access con within if condition?

Comment: con in 
`con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text)`

Comment: Updated. Now it'll work. Thanks for notifying @Santhosh Nayak.

Comment: Doesn't work? in the editor gives me conversion errors

Comment: Thank you very much I modified the code you give me and worked ?
i want to select your answer but i modify @SanthoshNayak code so i don't know who's answer to select?

Comment: No worries. It's up to you. Glad to know it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to say thank you for every one who contribute to answer my question.

I had modified the code for AT-2016 and Santhosh Nayak

so it works for me 100%.

```
  var query = (from con in db.Containers
                     join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
                     join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
                     where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
                     v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId && con.cont_Name.Contains(txtContNo.Text == null ? con.cont_Name : txtContNo.Text)
                     select new
                     {
                         cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                         vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                         VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
                         vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                         vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                         vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                         cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
                     }).ToList();


 var query2 = (from con in db.Containers
                      join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
                      join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
                      where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null &&
                      v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId && con.cont_customdec.Contains(txtCust.Text == null ? con.cont_customdec : txtCust.Text)
                      select new
                      {
                          cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                          vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                          VehicleState = v.vehl_state,
                          vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                          vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                          vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                          cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
                      }).ToList();




    if (txtContNo.Text != "")
    {
        rptVehl.DataSource = query;
        rptVehl.DataBind();


    }


    if (txtCust.Text != "")
    {
        rptVehl.DataSource = query2;
        rptVehl.DataBind();


    }
```

I won't to choose this as an accepted answer, thank you very much
AT-2016 and Santhosh Nayak